# Node can't find npm's dependent modules after unpacking binary tarball

Tags: node.js, npm

I downloaded the latest Node LTS Linux x86 binary tarball from here:

https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.12.0/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86.tar.xz

And extracted it here:

```
/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86
```

I added Node's bin/ directory to my path:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

And Node runs fine:

```
$ node -v
v8.12.0
```

However, when running npm, which is bundled with the Node binary tarballs, I get this:

```
$ npm -v
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'semver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Enabling module's debugging shows the paths it is searching for to find the semver module:

```
MODULE 19001: Module._load REQUEST semver parent: /home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/unsupported.js
MODULE 19001: looking for "semver" in ["/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/node_modules","/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/node_modules","/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules","/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules","/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/node_modules","/home/paul/dev/node_modules","/home/paul/node_modules","/home/node_modules","/node_modules","/home/paul/.node_modules","/home/paul/.node_libraries","/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node"]
```

In there I see this path:

```
/home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules
```

Which is where the semver module lives (as a dependent module of npm):

```
$ ls -al /home/paul/dev/node-v8.12.0-linux-x86/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/semver
total 80
drwxr-xr-x   3 paul paul   125 Sep 29 11:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 351 paul paul 12288 Sep 10 15:23 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 paul paul    27 Sep 10 15:23 bin
-rw-r--r--   1 paul paul   765 Feb 10  2018 LICENSE
-rw-r--r--   1 paul paul  1598 Aug 17 17:42 package.json
-rw-r--r--   1 paul paul   619 Aug 17 17:42 range.bnf
-rw-r--r--   1 paul paul 14655 Aug 17 17:42 README.md
-rw-r--r--   1 paul paul 36503 Aug 17 17:42 semver.js
```

So why can't Node resolve the semver module for npm?

For fun, I tried the latest 9.x release that supports x86, and it still fails, but gives a different message:

```
$ node -v
v9.11.2

$ npm -v
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/paul/dev/node/bin/npm'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:475:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

Something is definitely up with Node's module resolution.

Thanks!
-Paul

Answer (score 0):

I was having same problem with create-react-app 
I don't know how but adding 'sudo' worked for me.

$ npm start

---> Giving Error same as yours

$ sudo npm  start

---> Work Perfectly

hope it solve your problem